# Passing objects through intents in Android

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-intentservice

I wanted to clarify the process of passing a custom object (Which implements serializable) to a new activity in Android. After I create an intent I use the method putExtra with a string key and the object I want to pass. I then use getintent, and then get serializable extras. For some reason my object is brand new and not carrying over any of the data sent with it. My code looks like this.

This is the code I use to send the object

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Question5a1.this, ResultPage.class);
intent.putExtra("Avengers", avengers);
startActivity(intent);
```

and this is the code I use to receive the object in a different activity.

```
Intent prevPage = getIntent();
Avengers avengers = (Avengers) prevPage.getSerializableExtra("Avengers");
```

I was intializing the "Avengers" object outside of the onCreate block previously, and just started intiliazing it in the lines above.  Every time I tried to retrieve the String set by the object it was null. I just wanted to make sure I was correctly sending and retrieving the object.

Comment: Are you sure that `avengers` variable actually isn't `null`? Use a debugger and look at the contents of `prevPage`. You can add logging and see if there are any extras in the `Intent` and iterate through them to see their keys and values.

Comment: @DavidWasser I used the debugger last night and found out what I needed to do to restructure my code. Thanks.

Comment: You should create an answer to your own question and accept that. It will help others who may have a similar problem.